# m2eclipse and gmaven plugin

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, gmaven-plugin

I have a project that contains several groovy classes and m2e is not compiling those groovy classes.
I'm using eclipse STS (spring tools suit) with m2eclipse 1.3.1. 
Here is my the groovy plugin configuration in my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I found this wiki page from gmaven: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven. That could be a solution, but I don't want to change my pom.xml. Is there another solution to my problem? Other than start using another IDE (I tried IntelliJ and works fine with the groovy compiler plugin)